# Criteria of compactness of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Suppose $K$ is a linear operator in a separable Hilbert space $H$ such that for any Hilbert basis $\{e_i\}$ of $H$ we have $\lim_{i,j \to \infty} (Ke_i,e_j) = 0$.

Is it true that $K$ is compact?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is $K$ a linear operator?

Comment: To Tomás: yes, it is linear

Comment: To Davide: the exact formulation is the following. For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n$ such that $|(Ke_i, e_j)|< \epsilon$ for every $i,j>n$.

Comment: For a first question, that's a good one, +1. I'll remark that an operator on $H$ is compact iff it is weak-norm continuous, so the property does hold quite strongly for compact operators. Converse? Why I neither saw nor thought about this before puzzles me. How did you come up with the question? Is this an exercise in some book?

Comment: Can we conclude that $\lim_{i,j\to\infty} (K e_i,K e_j)=0$?

Comment: @julien: Your argument is okay, but you need to be careful: an operator is weak-norm continuous iff it has finite rank (if $T$ is weak-norm continuous then $\{x \in H: \lVert Tx\rVert \lt 1\}$ is weakly open, so contains a subspace of finite codimension and it follows that the kernel has finite codimension). An operator is compact iff *its restriction to the unit ball* is weak-norm continuous iff it is (bounded weak\*)-norm continuous.

Comment: Thanks for checking my careless statement, Martin. What I had in mind was: T is compact iff sequentially weak-norm continuous. Of course, the weak topology is not metrizable in infinite dimension and we need to restrict to bounded sets if we want this to be a topological statement. You might want to take this opportunity to go edit [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Some_general_properties)...

Comment: to julien: Thanks. Indeed it is an exercise from a book, but, unfortunately I know neither title nor the author.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, $K$ is compact.

Note first that we can assume that $K$ is selfadjoint; indeed, if $K$ satisfies the hypothesis, so do $K^*$ and $K\pm K^*$, and if we prove that the real and the imaginary parts of $K$ are compact, then we have that $K$ is compact.

Using the Weyl-von Neumann-Berg Theorem (II.4.1 or II.4.2 in Davidson's *C$^*$-algebras by example*) we can write
$$
K=A+T,
$$
where $A$ is selfadjoint and diagonal in some basis; and $T$ is compact. Being compact, $T$ satisfies the hypothesis and so $A=K-T$ does too. Now, since $A$ is diagonal, the hypothesis implies that its diagonal tends to zero, and so it is compact. Then $K$ is compact, being a sum of compacts.

To finish, note that it is essential that the property of small entries of $K$ holds for any basis. If we fix a single basis, it is possible to have operators $K$ satisfying $\langle Ke_i,e_j\rangle\to0$ (in the sense of the question) but not compact. Indeed, let
$$
K=\bigoplus_n\begin{bmatrix}1/n&\cdots&1/n\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 1/n&\cdots&1/n\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is an orthogonal sum of pairwise orthogonal projections, so it is an infinite-dimensional projection, thus not compact.

Comment: This is a great answer to a great question, +1.

Comment: Thanks, julien. I've always found the Weyl-von Neumann-Berg Theorem wonderful, and that section in Davidson's book really cool.

Comment: to Martin: Thanks a lot, especially for the example in the end.

Comment: You're welcome!