# $T$ is compact iff $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle\to 0$ as $i,j\to\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ be a bounded operator. Suppose $(e_i)$ is a countable orthonormal basis in $H$. Show that $T$ is compact if and only if $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle\to 0$ as $i,j\to\infty$.

Note: I could prove that if $T$ is compact then $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle\to 0$. I am stuck at the converse part.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402324/criteria-of-compactness-of-an-operator?rq=1

Comment: For T to be compact you have to assume that $\langle Te_i,e_j \rangle \to 0$ for every orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. This problem has been discussed and a counter-example given on MSE.

Comment: (Where the answer also shows that it's not enough to have small coefficients in just one basis.)